# Determining the number of nodes within a cycle for an MILP problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, matlab

I have a MILP problem that requires knowing the number of nodes within a cycle (there will be multiple depending on inputs). I believe this will involve tracing nodes/values within cycles using the node-arc matrix, but I am unsure how to construct the mathematical formulation to do so.

I am required to use MATLAB and Gurobi solver.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Trace the path until you hit the same node as the starting node.